# How to retrieve items from database using JSONArray

Tags: java, json, servlets

I'm trying to retrieve the data from the database by using `JSONArray`. My code works well but it only displays the last item in the database as number of items in the database.

My code is :

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
    JSONObject Obj = new JSONObject();
    Connection conn = null; 
    try {
        conn=prepareConnection();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println( "Error --> " + displayErrorForWeb(e1));
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println( "Error --> " + displayErrorForWeb(e1));
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        JsonElement commentObj;

        StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder(1024);
        sb1.append("insert into ").append(uname.trim()).append("vcomments values(?,?,?,?)");
        String sql1=sb1.toString();
        PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
         stmt1.setString(1,uname);
         stmt1.setString(2,message);
         stmt1.setInt(3,itemId);
         stmt1.setInt(4,albumId);
         int i=stmt1.executeUpdate();

        if(i!=1){
        myObj.addProperty("success", false);
    }
    else {
        myObj.addProperty("success", true);
    }
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;    
    String sql = null;

     try {     

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(1024);
        sb.append("select * from ").append(uname.trim()).append("vcomments").append(" where itemid=").append(itemId).append(" and albumid=").append(albumId);
        sql=sb.toString();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<JSONObject> CommArray=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

         while(rs.next()){
            Obj.put("uname",rs.getString("uname").trim());
            Obj.put("comment",rs.getString("comments").trim());
            CommArray.add(Obj);

            }    
         JSONArray arrayObj=JSONArray.fromObject(CommArray);
         commentObj=gson.toJsonTree(arrayObj);
         myObj.add("commentInfo", commentObj);
         out.println(myObj.toString());
         rs.close();                                                              
         stmt.close();                                                            
         stmt = null;                                                             


         conn.close();                                                            
         conn = null;                                                  

     }                                                              
     catch(Exception e){System.out.println( "Error --> " + displayErrorForWeb(e));}
```

The response received :

```
 {"success":true,"commentInfo":[{"uname":"shyam","comment":"erxdg"},{"uname":"shyam","comment":"erxdg"},{"uname":"shyam","comment":"erxdg"},{"uname":"shyam","comment":"erxdg"}]}
```

The database contains two items. And the last item is *erxdg*. Servlet sent the response back only last item.

Please anyone help me to  fix it..... Thanks...........

Comment: something may be wrong with your query. Can you verify that your resultSet contains different values than erxdh? It would appear it is returning the same element over and over

Comment: @75inchpianist No, My `Resultset` returning the all values in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new `JSONObject` for each resultset. Create one in the loop, and add it to the array. Otherwise, you're just replacing the fields for the old object, and adding another reference to it to the results.

```
while(rs.next()){
    //new line:
    JSONObject Obj = new JSONObject();
    // original part looks fine:
    Obj.put("uname",rs.getString("uname").trim());
    Obj.put("comment",rs.getString("comments").trim());
    CommArray.add(Obj);
}
```